# Triggering changes on Nest Auto Away

Tags: nest-api

The documentation for the Nest API is a little but unclear on what developers are allowed to do when a structure goes into Auto-Away state. Am I allowed to turn lights off, or take other actions when this happens, or am I only allowed to take action on explicit Home/Away events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do anything you want on Home/Away/Auto-Away/anything provided it doesn't go against the prohibitions in the Terms of Service.